# How to only retrieve data if the count of a column is over a certain amount

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's my query

```
SELECT news.*, count(followers.artist_id) as followers 
FROM news 
INNER JOIN followers ON news.artist_id = followers.artist_id 
GROUP BY followers.artist_id 
ORDER BY followers DESC
```

So I'm currently getting all the news ordered by the amount of followers for a particular artist.

What I want to do is only retrieve the news if the followers are over a certain amount, say 10.

So I tried to throw in a where clause

```
WHERE followers > 10
```

But I get an error that there's no such column in the where clause.

What can I do to achieve this? Could I make a fake column that holds the follower count?

Cheers

Comment: using `HAVING` instead. eg. `GROUP BY.... HAVING count(followers.artist_id) > 10 ....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT news.*, x.[followers]
FROM news
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT news.id, Count(followers.id) as [followers]
    FROM news 
    INNER JOIN followers ON news.artist_id = followers.artist_id 
    GROUP BY news.id
    HAVING Count(followers.id) > 10) as x on x.id = news.id
```

I assume that both tables (news and followers) have **id** column which uniquely identifies the row.